# Drawing a circle on google maps static link

Tags: android, google-maps

i'm trying to draw a circle on a static map by feeding `getCircleAsPolyline` with `Location` data and then encode with `PolyUtil.encode`, according to this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38100481/1520234.

unfortunately the output is not a circle but something strange like this:

[image: output]

can anybody kindly explain me why this happen and if it's possible to get a real circle and if so how?

thanks

**EDIT**

i apologize for not being very clear, i forgot to mention that actually my `getCircleAsPolyline` is slightly different from the one i linked since i used `SphericalUtil.computeOffset` to calculate the coordinates; anyway below is my `getCircleAsPolyline` function:

```
private static ArrayList<LatLng> getCircleAsPolyline(Location center, float radius) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> circlePath = new ArrayList<>();
    double step = 5.0;
    double centerLatitude = center.getLatitude();
    double centerLongitude = center.getLongitude();
    for (double angle = 0.0; angle < 360.0; angle += step) {
        LatLng circlePoint = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(
                new LatLng(centerLatitude, centerLongitude),
                radius,
                (90.0 - angle + 360.0) % 360.0
        );
        circlePath.add(circlePoint);
    }
    return circlePath;
}
```

but result is the one showed in picture

Comment: Do you use Static Maps API in Android app? If so, why don't you use a [Lite mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite) that show map as a static image? In this case you can draw Circle in lite mode using Circle class

Comment: thanks xomena, i didn't know about lite mode, i'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

For those who'll come here having the same problem, well I simply got it avoiding to encode the polyline: infact as long as I drop **PolyUtil.encode** and append points as **| lat, long |** I've been able to draw a perfect circle.