# Generate circle points from latitude and longitude from center point and radius

Tags: javascript, geometry, radius

I have (lat, lon) for the center of a circle.

I have a radius R in km.

My code

```
for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    let degrees = (i/steps)*360
    let radians = (Math.PI/180)*degrees
    let x = lat + radius * Math.cos(radians)
    let y = lon + radius * Math.sin(radians)
    coordinates.push([x,y])
}
```

returns an oval shape because of the latitude and variable radius is not in km, but in coordinates.

How can I adapt this code in order to generate a perfect circle?

Comment: I found [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10715947/4539276), which satisfies my needs!

Answer (score 0):

For not very large circle radius you can correct longitude dimension using division by  `cos(latitude)`, because meridian/parallel ratio depends on this value.